# Como referenciar atributos de um objeto dentro de uma função interna?

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo a simulação de um chuveiro, e não consigo referenciar os atributos sem que dê erro.

Para executar o código uso `docol.molhar()` no console.
Quando verifico `this.agua` por exemplo, ele consta como `undefined`. No entanto, se eu declarar e usar os atributos como variáveis, estes funcionam normalmente.

Código que não funciona:

```js
function chuveiro() //definição do Objeto
{
    /*this.marca = "Marca";
    this.serial = "Numero de Serie";
    this.lote = "Numero do Lote";*/
    this.agua = 20; //quant de agua em minutos
    this.min = 0;
    var chuva;

    //this.ligar = function() {console.log("bip")} ; //definição de função de objeto, a.k.a. método
    this.chover = function() 
    {
        if (this.agua > 0)
        { 
            this.agua--;
            console.log(`resta(m) ${this.agua} minuto(s) de agua`);
            this.min--;
            if (this.min < 1) clearInterval(chuva);
        }
        else
        {
            clearInterval(chuva);
            console.log("acabou a agua");
        }
    }
    this.molhar = function()
    {
        this.min = prompt("quantos minutos vc quer gastar?")
        chuva = setInterval(this.chover, 500);
    }
}

var docol = new chuveiro(); //Criação de uma instância do Objeto
docol.molhar();
```

Código que funciona:

```js
function chuveiro() //definição do Objeto
{
    /*this.marca = "Marca";
    this.serial = "Numero de Serie";
    this.lote = "Numero do Lote";*/
    var agua = 20; //quant de agua em minutos
    var min = 0;
    var chuva;

    //this.ligar = function() {console.log("bip")} ; //definição de função de objeto, a.k.a. método
    this.chover = function() 
    {
        if (agua > 0)
        { 
            agua--;
            console.log(`resta(m) ${agua} minuto(s) de agua`);
            min--;
            if (min < 1) clearInterval(chuva);
        }
        else
        {
            clearInterval(chuva);
            console.log("acabou a agua");
        }
    }
    this.molhar = function()
    {
        min = prompt("quantos minutos vc quer gastar?")
        chuva = setInterval(this.chover, 500);
    }
}

var docol = new chuveiro(); //Criação de uma instância do Objeto
docol.molhar();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade o problema é passar o método como argumento de `setInterval`. Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval#the_this_problem):

> *When you pass a method to `setInterval()` or any other function, it is invoked with the wrong `this` value.*
> *...*
> *Code executed by `setInterval()` runs in a separate execution context than the function from which it was called. As a consequence, the `this` keyword for the called function is set to the `window` (or `global`) object, it is not the same as the `this` value for the function that called `setTimeout`.*

Ou seja, ao fazer `setInterval(this.chover, 500);`, o método `chover` não executará com o mesmo `this` referente ao objeto em questão (em vez disso, o `this` dele é setado para o `window` ou o objeto `global`). Por isso que neste caso ele não enxerga mais os campos do objeto.

Uma solução é usar [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), que cria uma função igual à original, porém com o valor de `this` que quisermos. E como neste caso deve ser o próprio objeto, basta fazer `setInterval(this.chover.bind(this), 500);`. Ou seja:

```js
function chuveiro() {
    this.agua = 20;
    this.min = 0;
    var chuva;

    this.chover = function () {
        if (this.agua > 0) {
            this.agua--;
            console.log(`resta(m) ${this.agua} minuto(s) de agua`);
            this.min--;
            if (this.min < 1)
                clearInterval(chuva);
        } else {
            clearInterval(chuva);
            console.log("acabou a agua");
        }
    }
    this.molhar = function () {
        this.min = parseInt(prompt("quantos minutos vc quer gastar?"));
        chuva = setInterval(this.chover.bind(this), 500);
    }
}

var docol = new chuveiro();
docol.molhar();
```